# Couldn't display images under emacs-w3m on MacOS 10.9

Tags: macos, shell, emacs, terminal, w3m

I am using emacs 24.3.

I use the common setting that add to .emacs:

`(setq w3m-default-desplay-inline-images t)`

but it's not work. I also try to toggle to display image via `shortcut T` in emacs-w3m, it shows "Can't display images in this environment".

[image]

It works totally fine on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Are there any ways to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you install the executable of w3m, and did you try running it in the terminal to see what happens?  You should get a listing in the terminal of all available options for w3m if it is installed correctly:  `w3m version w3m/0.5.3, options lang=en,m17n,image,color,ansi-color,mouse,menu,cookie,ssl,ssl-verify,external-uri-loader,w3mmailer,nntp,ipv6,alarm,mark
usage: w3m [options] [URL or filename] options:  -t tab set tab width. . .`

Comment: @lawlist I have tried it in terminal, it also couldn't display image. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using emacs in a terminal?

Comment: @IqbalAnsari yeah, I have some work that on remote machines.

Comment: Oh then I guess you are out of luck, sorry, check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to start emacs without -nw flag.

Comment: As the previous right answer user is not active any more, you get the credit.

Comment: That's not exactly a reason to switch answers. The other answer was already accepted, and clearly states to try to start emacs without the -nw flag.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot display images in a terminal environment, to verify this do `M-x (display-images-p nil)` this will return `nil` in console emacs. You will need to start emacs in window environment without the `-nw` flag (I am assuming you are using it to start emacs)